# GetBaseFont() equal null in pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I extract text from pdf file using pdfbox,when I get font for some text in pdf it get null i don't why! although some another text in the same file i get its font.

using this code:

```
 protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
  String font=text.getFont().getBaseFont(); // equal null

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String font=text.getFont().getBaseFont(); // equal null
```

`PDFont.getBaseFont` is implemented to simply return the value of the **BaseFont** entry of the respective font dictionary.

Not all fonts provide a **BaseFont** entry in their font dictionary, though. In such a case that message will return `null`.

According to the PDF specification you can only expect fonts to have that entry if they are *Type0* (composite), *Type1*, or *TrueType* fonts. If they are *Type3*, they don't have that entry.

This actually makes sense: *Type3* fonts are pure PDF stuff down to their glyph definitions; thus, there is no base font to consider.

In case of *Type0* (composite) fonts you might actually consider looking at the descendant font (using `PDType0Font.getDescendantFont()`) and inspecting its **BaseFont** entry because the entry of the composite font is specified as a composition of the descendant's base font name and a CMap name.

And while all of the above is true for PDF following the specification, you have to get used to seeing PDFs in the wild which do not follow the spec 100%. As the base font entry is not always strictly necessary for PDF handling in general, there surely are PDFs in the wild which don't provide the base font entry in such cases.

Thus, always reckon with `null` values (or values not following the spec) here.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer,if this get null due to reasons you mentioned are there any other methods enable me to know the font?

Comment: For *Type3* fonts there isn't; on the other hand there most likely simply is no name to go with a *Type3* font. In case of fonts which should have a **BaseFont** entry but don't... well, have a look at the **FontName** and **FontFamily** entries in the **FontDescriptor**, and maybe in the font program itself.

Comment: So what I will do? please help me, now I read text from pdf and display it in html pages,which font I apply it for the text that its font has type3(equal null)?

Comment: *If it is Type3* (you would have to provide a sample PDF to make sure), then **there most likely is no usual font for it**. E.g. look at [this iText Type3 sample result](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter11/type3_example.pdf). This sample provides a Type3 font with two custom generated glyphs available as `D` and `S` representing a delta and a sigma, cf. the [sample source](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=200). The glyphs for Type3 fonts are defined in the PDF as vector graphic operations. You might want to extract those operations and draw them on a HTML canvas.

Comment: OK, I will give you the book i work on it. it is arabic book(1 page) some text has type1 font and the most text has type3 font.
Book Link:http://www.4shared.com/office/sO_qqqdcba/Test_Type3_Problem.html

Comment: Does that site really require registering or social network login? Or do i miss something?

Comment: No need for registeration, write me your mail and i will send you the book over mail

Comment: I've had a quick look into it. Indeed, the font is type 3. I'll look into it later whether there is some hint helping to find a replacement font for your task.

Comment: Ok,I will send you another mail for another inquiry related to this topic and please reply me here or via mail

Comment: I have not yet received another PDF. Looking at the first, though, I don't see any easy, generic way to find a replacement font: There is no indication that the font is for arabic characters, even **Encoding** and **ToUnicode** information indicate that the font is meant for Latin characters and assorted math symbols.