# How to change the coordinates of a text in a pdf page from lower left to upper left

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, coordinates, pdfbox

I am using PDFBOX and itextsharp dll and processing a pdf.
so that I get the text coordinates of the text within a rectangle. the rectangle coordinates are extracted using the itextsharp.dll.
Basically I get the rectangle coordinates from itextsharp.dll, where itextsharp uses the coordinates system as lower left. And I get the pdf page text from PDFBOX, where PDFBOX  uses the coordinates system as top upper left.
I need help in converting the Coordinates from lower left to upper left

**Updating my question**

Pardon me if you didn't understood my question and if not full information was provided.

well, Let me try to give more details from start.

I am working on a tool where I get a PDF in which a rectangle is drawn using some Drawing markups within a comment section. Now I am reading the rectangle coordinates using iTextsharp

```
PdfDictionary pageDict = pdReader.GetPageN(page_no);
PdfArray annotArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
```

where pdReader is PdfReader.

And the page text along with its coordinates is extracted using PDFBOX. where as I have a class created pdfBoxTextExtraction in this I process the text and coordinate such that it returns the text and **llx,lly,urx,ury** "line by line" please note line by line not sentence wise.

So I want to extract the text that lays within the Rectangle coordinates. I got stuck when the coordinates of the rectangle returned from itextsharp i.e llx,lly,urx,ury of a rectangle has an origin at **lower left** where as the text coordinates returned from PDFBOX has an origin at **upper left** .then I realised I need to adjust the y-axis so that the origin moves from lower left to upper left. for the I got the height of the page and height of the cropbox

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle mediabox = reader.GetPageSize(page_no);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle cropbox = reader.GetCropBox(page_no);
```

Did some basic adjustment

> lly=mediabox.Top - lly
>
> ury=mediabox.Top - ury

in some case the adjustment worked, whereas in some PDFs needed to do adjustment on cropbox

> lly=cropbox .Top - lly
>
> ury=cropbox .Top - ury

where as on some PDFs didn't worked.

All I need is help in adjusting the rectangle coordinates so that I get the text within the rectangle.

Comment: Y' = Ymax - Y. X' = X - Xmin.

Comment: Hmm, first I was going to say that `X' = X - Xmin` isn't relevant in this context, but it might be if that's how PdfBox "thinks". I'll update my answer once more.

Comment: As far as i remember PDFBox for text extraction uses 0,0 as upper left. I haven't checked, though.

Comment: Following your comments to @Bruno's answer I'm afraid there is quite some more information required to actually help you along. Please provide some code and sample PDF files to illustrate.

Comment: Concerning the edit: **a** the PDFs for which the mediabox variant worked... Did the cropbox variant also work for them? **b** the PDFs for which neither worked... Can you share sample documents?

Comment: hi @mkl.. sorry but cant share the sample documents.<br/> I guess i have found the adjustments for y-axis and the code is running properly. Currently i am testing on various PDFs <br/> Will post the adjustments once testing is done

Comment: btw thank you mkl and @Bruno's. Thanks alot....clear most of the topics regarding PDF

Comment: @mkl how do i provide you the sample file.. In this PDF itextsharp text coordination fails to extract proper text with coordination

Comment: *how do i provide you the sample file* - Share the PDF using e.g. public shares on google drive or dropbox and post the link here.

Comment: @mkl [Check the pdf here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YDw6_pdjfdQmpvUjAxVEg5ZDQ/view).. can you please review this pdf.. here the text extraction of the page is including extra space between the words

Comment: @BrunoLowagie [PDF FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YDw6_pdjfdQmpvUjAxVEg5ZDQ/view).. bruno can you please help out with such instance of PDFs where i am getting extra space between the word using itextsharp's PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage method

Comment: That PDF is weird: its page has the boxes `/CropBox[0 0 684 855]/BleedBox[27 27 657 828]/MediaBox[36 36 648 819]/TrimBox[36 36 648 819]`, i.e. a larger crop box than media box. This usually makes no sense and may befuddle your code.

Comment: yes @mkl i have noticed this. So is this the reason that the iTextsharp does not extract the text properly, as the PDF is not in  the proper format ??

Comment: The PDF content is even weirder... `-.232 Tc [(  P)-226.2(r)-231.8(e)-230.8(f)-238(a)-238.9(c)-228.9(e)]TJ` - First setting the character spacing to -(Width of space) and then adding distance again explicitly. I think iText upon seeing those big gaps assumes there to be free space between the characters and presents it as a space.

Comment: @mkl ... can you please suggest anything that can help me from such cases of files...?? or any suggestions that would help me out

Comment: @mkl [the attached images are output generated from itext and pdfbox](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_YDw6_pdjfdMV9HaVRTc2FjazQ&usp=sharing).. although pdfbox provides proper output as it reads the single charcter and their coordinates. i have created a method through which i merge the charter to words and than to sentence

Comment: @BrunoLowagie The `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` already removes the character spacing at the end of a text chunk for determining the chunk width. Unfortunately it uses `renderInfo.getSingleSpaceWidth()` to determine the space width (used in later comparisons with gap sizes), and that method includes the character spacing. Thus, the assumed space width is 0 here and the smallest gap is considered a space. This can be fixed.

Comment: @RAHILKAZI *can you please suggest anything that can help me from such cases of files* - unfortunately a (small) improvement of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` is necessary, see my comment to Bruno.

Comment: If @RAHILKAZI is a customer of iText Software, he should post a ticket to our issue tracker in which case, we'll look at it on the very short term. If he's not a paying customer, we'll put it on the TODO list with a low priority because the PDF is not what you could call a "normal PDF". It's more a *garbage in, garbage out* problem than a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate system in PDF is defined in ISO-32000-1. This ISO standard explains that the X-axis is oriented towards the right, whereas the Y-axis has an upward orientation. This is the default. These are the coordinates that are returned by iText (behind the scenes, iText resolves all CTM transformations).

If you want to transform the coordinates returned by iText so that you get coordinates in a coordinate system where the Y axis has a downward orientation, you could for instance subtract the Y value returned by iText from the Y-coordinate of the top of the page.

**An example:** Suppose that we are dealing with an A4 page, where the Y coordinate of the bottom is 0 and the Y coordinate of the top is 842. If you have Y coordinates such as `y1 = 806` and `y2 = 36`, then you can do this:

```
y = 842 - y;
```

Now `y1 = 36` and `y2 = 806`. You have just reversed the orientation of the Y-axis using nothing more than simple high-school math.

**Update based on an extra comment:**

Each page has a media box. This defines the most important page boundaries. Other page boundaries may be present, but none of them shall exceed the media box (if they do, then your PDF is in violation with ISO-32000-1).

The crop box defines the visible area of the page. By default (for instance if a crop box entry is missing), the crop box coincides with the media box.

In your comment, you say that you subtract llx from the height. This is incorrect. `llx` is the lower-left **x** coordinate, whereas the height is a property measured on the **Y** axis, **unless** the page is rotated. Did you check if the page dictionary has a `/Rotate` value?

You also claim that the values returned by iText do not match the values returned by PdfBox. Note that the values returned by iText conform with the coordinate system as defined by the ISO standard. If PdfBox doesn't follow this standard, you should ask the people from PdfBox **why** they didn't follow the standard, and **what** coordinate system they are using instead.

Maybe that's what mkl's comment is about. He wrote:

> Y' = Ymax - Y. X' = X - Xmin.

Maybe PdfBox searches for the maximum Y value `Ymax` and the minimum X value `Xmin` and then applies the above transformation on all coordinates. This is a useful transformation if you want to render a PDF, but it's unwise to perform such an operation if you want to use the coordinates, for instance to add content at specific positions relative to text on the page (because the transformed coordinates are no longer "PDF" coordinates).

**Remark:**

You say you need PdfBox to get the text of a page. Why do you need this extra tool? iText is perfectly capable of extracting and reordering the text on a page (assuming that you use the correct extraction strategy). If not, please clarify.

- Note that we recently decided to support Type3 fonts, although we weren't convinced that this makes sense (see [Text extraction is empty and unknown for text has type3 font using PDFBox,iText (difficult topic!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659463/text-extraction-is-empty-and-unknown-for-text-has-type3-font-using-pdfbox-itext) to understand why not).
- What some consider "wrong extraction" can often be "wrong interpretation" of what is extracted as explained in this mailing-list answer: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/66829/focus=66830
- There are other cases where we follow the spec, leading to results that are different than what PdfBox returns. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE for more info.

Comment: hi bruno, In some PDF itextsharp failed to extract the text and their coordinates so PDBOX came in picture, well for geeting the page height there are two thing to be consider 1) Mediabox 2) Cropbox.. i am stuck somewhere here between. In some PDF the mediabox height is same as cropbox height. And when i substract the llx from height to  transfrom Y-coordinate to the top of the page. the coordinates does not match the Text Coordinates returned from PDFBOX

Comment: Nevertheless: if the page is rotated, you have to take into account that X may become Y and Y may become X, so your typo led to an important extra caveat.

Comment: oops... Its LLY, Sorry for that mistake..And the lly is the cooridnates of the the rectangle,to be more specific. to transfrom the coords to Y-coordinate to the top of the page, i've done some adjustment to the cords of the rectangle ie Mediabox.top- lly-(Mediabox.top-cropbox.top). And there are some instance where the itextsharp returns extra space within the text thus the coordinates missmatch so PDFBOX is used it returns the coordinates properly. But the rectancle coords are returned from iTextsharp. So the cords of rectangle are to be transform to Y-coordinate to the top of the page

Comment: You cannot expect rectangle positions and text positions to coincide because text positions usually are given on the text baselines but some letters go below the baseline. Thus, your problem is not merely aa coordinate transformation but also the need to apply fuzzy checks.

Comment: @mkl: I don't understand a word of the comment by Rahil Kazi. I'm happy to see that you do. In any case RAHILKAZI: all the information that is returned by iText is correct. If another tool changes the correct information, then you are talking about a *feature*. That *feature* may or may not be available in iText, but before somebody can tell you if it is, you'll have to learn how to phrase your questions because in its current state, I have no clue what you mean by your comment.

Comment: I don't 100% understand his issue either, but his comment and question seem to indicate that he gets some rectangle data via iTextSharp and some text positions via PDFBox which don't match exactly. One assumption would be that this is due to text positions usually given by their base line start position. It's a guess, a pretty wild one.

Comment: Apart from the baseline, iText can also provide the ascender and the descender based on info retrieved from the font. Whatever PdfBox provides, it is based on information that is available to iText too.

Answer (score 0):

```
          if ((mediabox.Top - mediabox.Height) != 0)
            {
                topY = mediabox.Top;
                heightY = mediabox.Height;
                diffY = topY - heightY;
                lly_adjust = (topY - ury) + diffY;
                ury_adjust = (topY - lly) + diffY;
            }
            else if ((cropbox.Top - cropbox.Height) != 0)
            {
                topY = mediabox.Top;
                heightY = cropbox.Top;
                diffY = topY - heightY;
                lly_adjust = (topY - ury) - diffY;
                ury_adjust = (topY - lly) - diffY;

            }
            else
            {

                lly_adjust = mediabox.Top - ury;
                ury_adjust = mediabox.Top - lly;

            }
```

These are final adjustment done

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer the media box? I would have thought the crop box would be the main box to look at.